# What is the addFooterView counterpart for GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

ListView has the addFooterView method which is useful for showing a loading message. But GridView does not have this method. So, how do I add a footer view to a GridView like shown in Google Play?  [image: Google Play loading footer view]

Answer (score 6):

> Android BucketListAdapter
>
> This is an implementation of a bucket list adapter, similar to what
>   you see in the Google Play application. It features a grid-like layout
>   of list elements, with the advantage that you can still use list
>   headers and footers - something that's not possible with the standard
>   GridView.

Link: https://github.com/rzsombor/bucket-list-adapter

Comment: Thanks for you list-adapter, I need the same thing. But it doesn't support item pressed and item clicked transparently. It looks like I need to override the ListView to customize the behaviour too.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, GridView does not offer this sort of capability.

If you want a "click here for more" entry, I'd just lazy-load the data once the end of the current grid data is reached. You can look at CommonsWare's [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) , and try to adapt it to GridView.

Comment: I don't want a "click here for more" entry. I just want to show a "Loading..." message to let the user know that the are more items being requested from the server. These items can take a while to load. Isn't there a way to make an item span two-columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use a Relative layout, put the grid view and make a Linear layout with the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and it will put what ever you want underneath the Grid view, which is what I think is what you want.

Comment: But this wouldn't make it seamless like how it is in Google Play.

Comment: What they do is have a different xml file called something_footer. It looks "seamless" because they make the style the same. But is not inside the GridView.

Comment: You can download the Google play apk, rename it to .zip extract it and look at the xml files they used.

Comment: Hmm... but it seems like it is inside the GridView because the scroll bar is encompassing the Loading message item. I'll try to give a look at Google Play's xml later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the endless scroll listener as the gridview's scroll listener. By using the scroll listener you can get the current position. when the end is reached show the custom loading view and when the loading from network is completed(AsyncTask or Loader completed) you can hide the loading view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, Use OnScrollListener to monitoring the scroll position, when scrolling to the last item, you can controll the visibility of the loading view.

```
        @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
            mOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem,
                    visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        }
        // The count of footer view will be add to visibleItemCount also are
        // added to totalItemCount
        if (visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
            // If all the item can not fill screen, we should make the
            // footer view invisible.
        } else if (!mIsLoading
                && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount)
                && mCurrentScrollState != SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mIsLoading = true;
            if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
            }
        }
    }

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <com.baidu.hao123.module.video.view.LoadMoreGridView
                    android:id="@+id/gv_movie_home"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:numColumns="3"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dip"
                    android:paddingRight="13dip"
                    android:paddingTop="10dip"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:verticalSpacing="12dip" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/auto_load_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:visibility="gone" 
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
                    android:layout_width="23dip"
                    android:layout_height="23dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/loadingText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/loading"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_ff555555"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fontSize_middle" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```